# Regex for numbers and credit cards

Tags: regex

I need to create a regex to

```
1234 IGNORE SPACE 56XX IGNORE SPACE IF ANY XXXX IGNORE SPACE IF ANY XXXX
```

Maninly I need to match

```
123456xxxxxxxxxx or
1234 56xx xxxx xxxx
```

How to ignore the spaces ?

Comment: `\d{4}\s?\d{4}\s?\d{4}\s?\d{4}` if you want the optional spaces to be every four digits. Note that there are more precise ways to identify valid credit card numbers, in particulars because some of the numbers are a checksum of the rest. Check [the wikipedia page on Payment Card Number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Payment_card_number#Structure) and [Luhn algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luhn_algorithm) for more info

Comment: You can also use the shorter, but *slightly* less efficient `\d{4}(?:\s?\d{4}){3}`

Comment: If this is purely for matching credit card numbers, you should consider using the [Luhn Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luhn_algorithm) for validation, perhaps first remove all white space and check that length is 16-19 characters.

Comment: Tnx all, it's matching perfectly fine..